# CkEditor and Angular Material 2 Tabs

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-material

I use angular-cli, angular-material 2 and I try to use the CKEditor (ng2-ckeditor).

When I insert the CkEditor directly in the HTML (inside one div) there is no issue everything works.

But when I move the CkEditor code under the following structure:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Another label description">
        Contents 1
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Label description">
      <div>
        <md-card>
          <md-card-header>
            <md-card-title>
              This is a title
            </md-card-title>
          </md-card-header>
          <md-card-content>
            <ckeditor name="htmlTextValue"
                      [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent"
                      [config]="{uiColor: '#99000'}"
                      (change)="onChange($event)"
                      (ready)="onReady($event)"
                      (focus)="onFocus($event)"
                      (blur)="onBlur($event)"
                      debounce="500">
            </ckeditor>
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
```

it fails and here is the stacktrace from the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null
    at b (ckeditor.js:331)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:327)
    at a.m (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:251)
    at e (ckeditor.js:231)
    at Object.load (ckeditor.js:231)
```

Here are the important info from the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Here is my the code for my component:

```
  ckeditorContent = 'This is a text';

  onChange($event) {
    console.log('Change');
    console.log($event);

  }

  onReady($event) {
    console.log('OnReady');
    console.log($event);

  }

  onFocus($event) {
    console.log('Focus');
    console.log($event);
  }

  onBlur($event) {
    console.log('Blur');
    console.log($event);
  }
```

I tried the ckeditor builder as well in order to add the divarea plugin but with no luck.

Unfortunately I cannot create a plunker for this since angular-cli is not supported right now.

Do you have any idea why?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although this is not a solution or why this is happening I found a workaround. If I move the CkEditor in a tab that will be immediately visible when the app loads this component then everything works.

Comment: There is an issue opened in github https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/124.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed this problem by using this trick (dirty fix but working).

First, decorate ckeditor in your HTML template so that it will be visible only when method isVisible() returns true:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isVisible()">
    <ckeditor data="" [config]="ckEditorConfig" 
    (dataChange)="newData($event)" debounce="500"></ckeditor>
</ng-container>
```

Then in your TypeScript, add method isVisible() as follow. This methods needs that you inject ElementRef (adding it in your component constructor):

```
constructor(
  // add this line and import ElementRef:
  // import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
  private elementRef: ElementRef
) {
// keep any existing code that exists
}

isVisible(): boolean {
  const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  return element.offsetParent !== null;
}
```

Doing so, CKEditor will be instantiated only when component is visible (supposing that when component is visible, it has finished loading).

Note that the use of ElementRef can make your application more vulnerable (see : **https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef**)